# Rotate transition on :after psuedo-element not working

Tags: html, css, transform, transition, pseudo-element

I have an icon font that I am using as the content for my `:after` pseudo-element. When a click event is triggered, the parent of this pseudo element gets a class of `.active` and it slides up. I am trying to get the pseudo element to rotate 180 degrees using a transition. For some reason it does not work for me during development in Google Chrome. I attempted a test in Codepen on the same browser and everything is working fine.

Here's my css:

```
.deals-container-mobile p:after {
    content:"\e017";
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: 'vicons';
    font-size: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 13px;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}

.deals-container-mobile.active p:after {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Note I left out prefixing for simplicity but if you need to see it I can include.

Basically when the container is clicked, it gets a class of active, and it slides up. The `:after` psuedo element is initially an arrow pointing down. When the container slides up, I want the arrow to rotate to point up. The transform occurs, and the arrow points up, but there is no transition.

Thanks!

Comment: Add it to the `.active` class too?

Comment: Moving it instead would work better probably.